# Converting string to Bool and testing for IF statement in Swift

Tags: swift

So I am trying to take thee first index of a string (fullName) and test it to see if it matches all vowels lower and uppercased... for some reason when I use the .startIndex I test one letter at a time with a If statement.

Ia there a way to test all vowels at once ()I tried || in between each and it gave me the error "cannot convert string to Bool". Appreciate any help.

```
func lyricsForName(lyricsTemplate: String, fullName: String) -> String {

    let shortName = shortNameFromName(name: fullName)
    let index = fullName[fullName.startIndex]
    if index== ("a","A"){

        let lyrics = lyricsTemplate
            .replacingOccurrences(of:"<FULL_NAME>", with: fullName)
            .replacingOccurrences (of:"<SHORT_NAME>", with: fullName )

        return lyrics
    }else{
        let lyrics = lyricsTemplate
            .replacingOccurrences(of:"<FULL_NAME>", with: fullName)
            .replacingOccurrences (of:"<SHORT_NAME>", with: shortName )

        return lyrics
```

Comment: index it is not a good name for a character. `if String(fullName.characters.prefix(1)).uppercased() == "A"`

Comment: mhhh interesting question. but why you need it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it.  You can use an array of vowels and then test if the array contains the first character:

```
let fullName = "Albert"

let vowels = "aeiouAEIOU".characters    

if let first = fullName.characters.first, vowels.contains(first) {
    print("\(fullName) starts with a vowel")
}
```

> Albert starts with a vowel

Note: Using `fullName.characters.first` is safer than `fullName[fullName.startIndex]` because the latter will crash for an empty `String`.

Comment: and with `fullName.characters.first.uppercased` you can half the `vowels` array

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as previously answered, but this is a more Swifty way using the available APIs:

```
extension String {
    var firstThreeLettersAreVowels: Bool {
        guard characters.count >= 3 else {
            return false
        }

        let firstThreeLetters = substring(to: index(startIndex, offsetBy: 3))
        let isAllVowels = CharacterSet(charactersIn: firstThreeLetters).isSubset(of: CharacterSet.vowels)
        return isAllVowels
    }

    var isLower: Bool {
        return CharacterSet(charactersIn: self).isSubset(of: CharacterSet.lowercaseLetters)
    }

    var isUpper: Bool {
        return CharacterSet(charactersIn: self).isDisjoint(with: CharacterSet.lowercaseLetters)
    }
}

extension CharacterSet {
    static var vowels: CharacterSet {
        return CharacterSet(charactersIn: "AEIOUYaeiouy")
    }
}
```

Or the one liner (without length check) is

```
extension String {
    var firstThreeLettersAreVowels: Bool {
        return CharacterSet(charactersIn: substring(to: index(startIndex, offsetBy: 3)))
                    .isSubset(of: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "AEIOUYaeiouy"))
    }
}
```

This allows you rely on existing APIs rather than trying to do the work yourself, and it should be pretty fast.

Comment: it think it was a typo `thee` means `the`

Comment: anyway this guard is wrong `guard characters.count >= 3 else`

Comment: it should be check it there are less then 3 letters `guard characters.count < 3 else`

Comment: The guard is correct. https://www.natashatherobot.com/swift-guard-better-than-if/

Comment: oh sorry - i mixed it up - yes you are right  - i forget it should be true and otherwise it do the `else` and `return false` if `chars.count` one of `0,1,2`

Comment: haha no problem. I have to constantly remind myself that guard is opposite from an if.

Comment: lets play: more gerneric :) https://gist.github.com/muescha/d988a10698d16356b79c460ca9e6507a

Comment: Cool! It might be even better if you pass in a range instead.

Comment: you can create an CharacterSet from Range and pass this direct

Comment: not too much generic ;) added test case `"ABD".isFirstLetters(count: 3, of: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "A"..."C")) // false` and `"ABD".isFirstLetters(count: 3, of: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "A"..."D")) // true`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134512/discussion-between-peejweej-and-muescha).

Answer (score 0):

all kudos please to [PEEJWEEJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1852164/peejweej) answer

the characterset was his idea :)

i made it only more general

```
import Foundation

extension String {
    func isFirstLetters(count: Int, of characterSet: CharacterSet) -> Bool {

        guard characters.count >= count else {
            return false
        }

        let firstLetters = substring(to: index(startIndex, offsetBy: count))
        let isInSubset = CharacterSet(charactersIn: firstLetters).isSubset(of: characterSet

        )
        return isInSubset
    }
}

extension CharacterSet {
    static var vowels: CharacterSet {
        return CharacterSet(charactersIn: "AEIOUYaeiouy")
    }
}
```

some Test cases:

```
"abcDEf".isFirstLetters(count: 3, of: .vowels) // false
"aioDEf".isFirstLetters(count: 3, of: .vowels) // true

"abcDEf".isFirstLetters(count: 1, of: .vowels) // true
"bbcDEf".isFirstLetters(count: 1, of: .vowels) // false
"ibcDEf".isFirstLetters(count: 1, of: .vowels) // true

"ABcdef".isFirstLetters(count: 3, of: .uppercaseLetters) // false
"ABDdef".isFirstLetters(count: 3, of: .uppercaseLetters) // true

"abBABcdef".isFirstLetters(count: 3, of: .lowercaseLetters) // false
"abbABDdef".isFirstLetters(count: 3, of: .lowercaseLetters) // true


"ABD".isFirstLetters(count: 3, of: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "A"..."C")) // false
"ABD".isFirstLetters(count: 3, of: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "A"..."D")) // true
```

debug info:

```
extension CharacterSet {
    var characters: [Character] {
        var result: [Character] = []
        for plane: UInt8 in 0...16 where self.hasMember(inPlane: plane) {
            for unicode in UInt32(plane) << 16 ..< UInt32(plane + 1) << 16 {
                if let uniChar = UnicodeScalar(unicode), self.contains(uniChar) {
                    result.append(Character(uniChar))
                }
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}



print(CharacterSet.uppercaseLetters.description)
//<Foundation._SwiftNSCharacterSet: 0x6000000271a0>

print(String(CharacterSet.vowels.characters))
//AEIOUYaeiouy

print(CharacterSet.vowels.characters)
// ["A", "E", "I", "O", "U", "Y", "a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "y"]
```